# Aumento del valor de registros cada 3 campos

Tags: php, mysql

[[image: Tabla que almacena los montos de las cuotas]Se me presenta el problema de que al hacer el INSERT debo aumentar el valor del monto cada 3 campos, porque son cuotas y cada 3 cuotas debe haber un aumento del 20% del monto anterior, como pueden ver en la imagen el aumento lo hace bien pero me inicia a partir del campo costo 3 y debe ser del campo costo 4, mostrare la funcion en la que realizo el aumento y la insercion de los datos, como ven tengo la variable $aumenta = 3 que es la que me genera el aumento cada 3 campos, pero como se ve en la tabla al comenzar hace el aumento a partir del costo 3, ya en los siguientes si lo hace cada 3. Y intente igualando la variable a 4 y si hace el aumento a partir del costo 4, pero al realizar el otro aumento lo hace cada 4 campos, tendria que quedar de esta manera costo 1: 20000, costo2: 20000, costo 3: 20000, costo 4: 24400, costo 5: 24400, costo 6: 24400, costo 7: 28800, costo 8: 28800, costo 9: 34560, costo 10: 34560](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXpCD.png)

```
function cuotas($cantidad,$monto){

$query = "INSERT INTO cuotas (cantidad) VALUES('$cantidad')";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);

$val = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

$campos = "";
$valores = "";
$porcentaje = 0.2;
$aumenta = 3;

for($i = 1; $i <= $cantidad; $i++){
  if(($i>0) && ($i % $aumenta)==0):
    $monto = $monto*(1+$porcentaje);
  endif;
  $campos .= 'costo' . $i . ' , ';
  $valores .= '' . $monto . ' , ';
}

if($campos != ''):
  $campos = substr($campos, 0, -2);
  $valores = substr($valores, 0, -2);
endif;

$query2 = "INSERT INTO costo_cuotas(id_cantidad,$campos)VALUES($val,$valores)";
$sql .= implode(",", $valores).")";
$sql2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

if($sql>0 && $sql2>0):
  header('Location:admin.php');
else:
  echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
endif;
}
```

Comment: Luis, segun te entiendo, despues de usar tu funcion, la primera fila deberia quedar: costo1=20000, costo2=20000, costo3=20000, costo4=24000, costo5=24000, costo6=24000. Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Y por cierto, otra pregunta. Lo que intentas hacer es insertar esa información en otra tabla, cierto? En la tabla `cuotas`? O quieres que la informacion que ya esta en la tabla que muestras se actualice?

Comment: Saludos kenny, exactamente asi como dices debe quedar la primera fila, y si esa fila tuviera 9 campos llenos luego del campo 6 aumentarle otro 20% mas y asi sucesivamente segun haya campos llenos. No en la tabla cuotas solo se va a guardar un solo valor que es la cantidad de cuotas que va a pagar el usuario, yo le digo 6 cuotas entonces en la tabla costo_cuotas se tienen que guardar 6 montos. Logicamente tengo esas dos tablas relacionadas.Y si necesito es insertar la informacion, no que se actualice cuando la muestre.

Comment: Mis ultimas preguntas. El substring lo estas haciendo para quitar la coma y espacio de al final, cierto? Y tambien, estas seguro que quieres hacer un insert? No seria mejor un update para actualizar los datos que ya tienes? Que problema especifico tienes? No inserta? No te muestra bien los valores? Te pregunto porque no veo por ninguna parte que estas sacando el 20%. Podrias [edit] tu pregunta para incluir todo esto?

Comment: Exacto el substring lo hago para quitar eso.! Si estoy seguro que debo hacer un insert, esos datos que tengo alli solo fueron para verificar que mi funcion funcionaba.

Comment: No Kenny hasta ahora no he hecho ningun aumento del 20%, porque de verdad no hayo como hacer para recorrer los campos.!

Answer (score 0):

Buen día

Lo imagen que acompañas a tu planteamiento no muestra el efecto esperado o por lo menos el hasta ahora logrado por código; **partiendo que muestra únicamente la estructura de la tabla a llenar te comento a continuación**.

crea en php un array que mediante iteracción llenes con los valores a insertar en cada campo; ejemplo:

```
$totalValores=12; // Numero de campos que contiene tu tabla
$valorInsertar = 20000;  // De la imagen corresponde al campo costo1 con id_cantidad=1
$porcentajeIncremento=0.20; // Porcentaje que se incrementa
$aumentaCadaPagos=3; // Cada cuantos pagos aumentas; en tu planteamiento lo aumentas cada 3
$valores= array();

for($i=0; $i<$totalValores;$i++){
   if (($i>0) && (($i % $aumentaCadaPagos)==0))
      $valorInsertar=$valorInsertar*(1+$porcentajeIncremento);

   $valores[]=$valorInsertar;
}
// al terminar la iteracción anterior tendrás los valores 
// Ahora armar el SQL INSERT

$cSQL="INSERT INTO CUOTAS VALUES("; //  Asumo la tabla de la ilustación se llama "cuotas".

$cSQL.=implode(",", $valores).")";

// y lo pasas a tu proceso donde se envia la petición a ejecutarse a la BD.
```

Te sea de utilidad o te de una idea para tu necesidad.

Comment: La imagen la coloque para mostrar como guarda los datos mi funcion, a la cual no le he aplicado ningun aumento. Voy a probar lo que me planteas Roberto, y luego paso por aqui. Gracias.

Comment: Tu planteamiento editalo y coloca las estructuras de las tabla a llenar y que quieres hace en cada una. Tienes **cuotas** y **costo_cuotas**, es necesario coloques estructura de ambas tablas o solo la que necesites llenar para comprender mejor lo que quieres. (Veo eliminaste de respuesta lo que comentaste colocarias), calquier actualización hazla en tu planteamiento.

Comment: Roberto he logrado que me inserte bien, pero resulta que el aumento que hace es demasiado grande. Aumenta 4 veces mas la cantidad anterior. Mira como queda mi fila. costo1: 20000 , costo2: 20000 costo 3: 20000, costo4: 80000 costo5: 80000 costo6: 80000 costo7: 80000
costo 8: 320000 costo9: 320000 costo10: 320000. Si te fijas aumenta 4 veces mas la cantidad, no veo el error de porque hace eso.

Comment: Si roberto porque en cuotas inserto nada mas la cantidad de cuotas que va a tener el curso. Por ejemplo 5 cuotas. Alli recupero esa cantidad y segun lo que ponga inserto la cantidad de veces en la otra tabla que es costo_cuotas. El problema ahora es el aumento demasiado grande que hace. No del 20% si no 4 veces mas del monto anterior.

Comment: Respecto al ncremento que al parecer es 4 veces; mira el porcentaje; si es 20% su incremente debes multiplicar el valor actual por 1.2, si es 30% debe ser 1.3 el factor, es decir el N% hace **1+ (N/100)** para obtener el factor a usar, pruebalo en hoja de calculo o calculadora para corroborarlo, veras que es así y mira tu codigo donde esta el error.

Comment: Encontrado el error Roberto, solo era que en la multiplicacion para sacar el porcentaje no habia colocado la variable que era. Ahora Roberto una ultima duda, en la variable $aumentaCada = 3, en la tabla me guarda bien y hace el aumento bien, pero empieza a aumentar del campo 3 en adelante. El aumento debe hacerse cada 3 campos. Osea a partir del campo 4 o 7 o 10. Mira como queda: costo 1: 20000 costo 2: 20000 , costo3: 24000 , costo 4: 24000 costo 5 : 24000 costo 6: 28800 como te fijas el aumento comienza en el campo 3. Debe comenzar en el campo 4.

Comment: Y iguale la variable $aumentaCada = 4; y si comienza a partir del 4 campo, pero luego el otro aumento lo hace 4 campos despues. Y debe ser de 3 campos en 3 campos. Donde puede estar el error.

Comment: Edita tu plantemiento agregando lo que tienes, poniendo lo que esta fallando y en dado caso una breve explicación de la implementación (el flujo de información) no se hasta el momento tu estructura y flujo de datos completo; lo que imposibilita entender (a mi) lo que dices; puedo especular y asumir, pero lo idóneo es que coloques lo que tienes, que ocurre y que deberia ocurrir asi como en que momento en usado (en el caso de funciones) en que momento es usado.

Comment: Perfecto roberto!